# Running autofilter VBA macro that has a pop up to enter date

Tags: excel, vba, button, user-input, userform

I am a bit new to this whole VBA/Excel Macros thing so I am trying my best to find the solutions I need, so far I've done well - but finally hit a dead-end.

I have a code that is AutoFiltering my data table, and then Sorting base off specific columns (see below).

```
Sub FGReport()
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sorted Report FG").ListObjects("Table25").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= "1085"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sorted Report FG").ListObjects("Table25").Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:= "<>$0"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sorted Report FG").ListObjects("Table25").Range.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:= "<1/1/2018", Operator:=xlAnd
    'ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sorted Report FG").Range("Table25[[#Headers],[LastSoldDate]]").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sorted Report FG").ListObjects("Table25").Sort. SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sorted Report FG").ListObjects("Table25").Sort. SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("Table25[LastSoldDate]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sorted Report FG").ListObjects("Table25").Sort. SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("Table25[TotalInventoryValue]"), SortOn:= xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sorted Report FG").ListObjects("Table25").Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
```

Where the code is auto filtering the date (Line 4). I would like it to prompt the user to enter the date manually. I figured doing this with a UserForm would be the most appropriate (picture below)

[image: img1]

I just have no clue how to prompt the UserForm to appear during that line of the code, and have it function by entering the date, clicking Enter, and then continue running the original FGReport() macro.

Let me know if more information is needed! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Next time, when adding a code snippet, highlight all of your code and press Ctrl + K on your keyboard to properly format it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Initially I'd recommend an input box and check that the input is valid:

```
Dim myDate as String

myDate = InputBox("Please enter a date (dd/mm/yyyy)", "Date filter", Format(Now() - 7, "dd/mm/yyyy"))

If IsDate(myDate) Then
   ' Continue with logic
Else
    MsgBox "Invalid date"
End If
```

Be warned that IsDate is a pretty flaky function, but you can go on to make this code fancier, if you see fit.

Comment: What is it that makes `IsDate` flaky?

Comment: @NeepNeepNeep would this bypass the need for the UserForm completely? Or would this be the code tied to the UserForm?

Comment: @IREVEL type `InputBox "test"` + ENTER in the immediate pane (Ctrl+G), you'll answer that question fast enough. (spoiler: the fully-qualified name is `VBA.Interaction.InputBox`, i.e. same module as the `MsgBox` function - yes, it replaces your userform entirely.... although a UserForm has other advantages, like, you could embed the validation and actively *prevent* the user from okaying the modal dialog with invalid input)

Comment: Thank you both for your help. I ended up incorporating the 'InputBox' before running any of the auto filtering/sorting. Had it populate into a specific cell in a hidden sheet, and then referenced that cell as the date to sort in the Main Sub. Worked wonderfully. Thanks again!

Comment: @MathieuGuindon IsDate is notoriously permissive and will allow pretty much any format that comes along, whatever your regional settings, i.e. "31/12/2018", "12/31/2018" and so on.  That said, it is useful as a final arbiter for valid leap year dates

Comment: @MathieuGuindon yes, it precludes the need for a UserForm & yes, you could employ a UF and include extra code for a more robust user experience